# How to import React.js as script in html?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to import reactjs or any framework app in html.
Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Bot</title>
    <style>
      .chatbot-goes-here {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 5rem;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chatbot-goes-here"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

my index.js

```
const x = document.getElementById('chatbot-goes-here');
x.innerHTML = `<h1>hi</h1>`
```

Now in "index.js" i want my react app logic which is changing the "div" with id="chatbot-goes-here". So the idea is this index.js file will be hosted on cloud instance and someone can include the div and script file to use the chatbot.

Comment: Just start from here https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Answer (score 4):

you can import react in your html file using cdn link, You can copy the following template i have designed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>React practice</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="root"></div>
     

     <!-- React CDN Link -->
     <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
     <!-- React-DOM CDN Link -->
     <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Babel CDN Link -->
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Linking index.js file -->
     <script src="index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to add `type="text/babel"` on your script tag. And don't need to ask for upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using react cdn :

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.js">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.9.3/babel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script type="text/babel">
    const className = 'container';
    const children = 'Hello World';
    const props = {children, className};

    const element = <div {...props} />;

    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It was good at the time but now it's deprecrated. The header is created to add script and link tags and the body is used for html element.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure to understand fully what you want. For what I understood if you want to import `reactjs` or any framework app in html you can use CDN or other similar links.

https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html

```
<script crossorigin src="YOUR FRAMEWORK LINK HERE"></script>
```

For exemple using **react** it looks like that :

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

More CDN libraries can be found [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries)